# Wordpress "more" tag doesn't display content.

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have been using the WordPress More tag on a custom page template. The content before the more tag will display fine but when i click the read more link the page re-loads but no content after the tag is displayed.

Here is the custom page code for i was told would fix the issue of the tag not displaying but now i am getting the new issue i just described. The previous issue i had was that the more tag would not display so i added the code below which now displays it but the content after the tag will not display no matter that i do

```
<?php global $more; $more = 0; ?>
<?php the_content('Continue Reading'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a plugin or another filter altering the_content() this can happen.

Try something like this

```
apply_filters('the_content',get_the_content( 'Continue Reading' ));
```

More info here
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content